# Functional interfaces for reference classes

Tags: r, oop, r-s4, reference-class, r-s3

I am trying to figure out the conceptual implications of providing a *functional user interface* to reference classes (or indeed S4/S3 classes). In short, I am concerned that if I write code that looks like as below, then it is equivalent to writing functional code.

Here is a simple linear regression class:

```
linRegClass = setRefClass('linRegClass',
                          fields = list(formulaReg = 'formula',
                                        dataReg = 'data.frame'),
                          methods = list(doReg = function() {
                            lm(.self$formulaReg, data = .self$dataReg)
                          }))

linRegInstance = linRegClass$new(dataReg = cars, 
                    formulaReg = as.formula(speed ~ dist))
linRegInstance$doReg()
class(linRegInstance)
```

The object-oriented interface is not very user friendly, so as in [Martin Morgan's slides](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2010/HeidelbergNovember2010/ReferenceClasses-Morgan.pdf), I will write a functional user interface for the underlying reference class:

```
fnLinReg = function(formulaReg, dataReg) {
  linRegInstance = linRegClass$new(formulaReg = formulaReg, 
                                   dataReg = dataReg)
  linRegInstance$doReg()
}

## use the functional interface
fnLinReg(dataReg = cars, formulaReg = as.formula(speed ~ dist))
```

Now this functional interface is observationally equivalent to a purely functional

```
fnLinReg2 = function(formulaReg, dataReg) {
  lm(formula = formulaReg, data = dataReg)
}

## use the pure function
fnLinReg2(dataReg = cars, formulaReg = as.formula(speed ~ dist))
```

I am trying to figure out whether this is because my example is pathologically simple, but I still wonder if there is any point in writing reference classes and then wrapping them in functional interfaces versus writing purely functional code.

Any detailed examples would help greatly.

Comment: Your example very stilted. Any kind of OO is bad for this example: you're not storing the class and using its methods later, you simply want the call to `lm`, so of course the pure function will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated constructors can be defined using the `initialize` method, which will automatically be called when you call `new`. I've modified your example to contain the initialize method, and a new field to store the regression result, because `initialize` will always return the `referenceClass`:

```
linRegClass = setRefClass('linRegClass',
                          fields = list(formulaReg = 'formula',
                                        dataReg = 'data.frame',
                                        result = 'lm'),
                          methods = list(doReg = function() {
                            lm(.self$formulaReg, data = .self$dataReg)
                          },
                          initialize = function(formulaReg, dataReg, ...) {
                            formulaReg <<- formulaReg
                            dataReg <<- dataReg
                            result <<- .self$doReg()
                          }))
```

So now we simply have:

```
linRegInstance <- linRegClass$new(dataReg = cars, 
                                    formulaReg = as.formula(speed ~ dist))
linRegInstance$result
```

Comment: less verbose variable names and class names also would help!

Comment: Ha, I refuse to use less descriptive variable names. ;) Thanks for your answer. Could you give an example of a more elaborate example where interfacing to a reference class makes sense?

Comment: It makes more sense to use it when you have an object, rather than a function. Like a particular data-type, or dataset (if you have a set of common analyses you want to perform).

Comment: Ya, it is kinda dawning on me now. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you will run into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18893290/1414455) with complex constructors with no defaults.

Comment: There's two parts to that. One: `...` should be added as an extra argument to `initialize` for inheritance to work properly. I forgot that, so I've edited my answer.  Two, in the linked question's case, they should really define an pseudo-abstract class that is parent to both.

Comment: I actually have no idea if R can handle things like abstract classes or private methods.

Comment: No private methods, that's for sure.

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing stopping you from instantiating a class you've designed to be abstract either ;)